# Manga where a girl possesses a maid during an interview process for a wizard

Tags: story-identification, manga, wizards

It was a story where this girl possesses a maid character during an interview process for a wizard or something. I think the girl has pink hair and goes on a couple of adventures with the wizard and friends and she wields a hammer. I read this a while ago and I cannot remember the name for the life of me.

Comment: Charcuterie? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charcuterie

Comment: @Desperate Manga Binger - Hi, welcome to the site. I assumed you meant to type 'character' rather than 'charcuterie,' so I edited the question accordingly. If I'm mistaken, please edit the question yourself to correct that. By the way, was this story in full colour or mostly black & white?